# Launch Gedit while sshing in terminal

Tags: terminal, ssh

I know i can do it in linux, anything similar in osx?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly make sure X11 is installed (it's an optional install on the OS X dvd)

You need to ssh in with X11 forwarding.

Open terminal and type `ssh -X username@host`  where username and host are the relevant details.

This will log you in.  Once logged in type `gedit` and the X11 server on your mac will start and show the gEdit window.

Comment: hm got Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: is you're linux ssh server setup to forward X11 packets?

Comment: see edit, make sure X11 is installed on your mac too

Comment: its installed and enabled. Just another bit of diagnostic help when i echo display i get a blank line

Comment: when I echo $DISPLAY, it says localhost:10.0

Comment: With Apple's X11 the $DISPLAY value is a socket not localhost

Comment: Thats what I got when I SSH'ed into the linux box.  On my mac I just get a blank like like @Jacopo.   But gEdit runs and other apps run perfectly

Comment: hm, i feel like this question might be more applicable on serverfault,as it seems more and more like the issue is on the server side

Comment: on the server have you configured SSH server to forward X11 packets?